# Redirect Subdomain to a different host/server

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain

I'm attempting to redirect a subdomain to a different host/server.  I own both accounts.

I created an A Record on the first host specifying the IP address of the second host.  I then created a subdomain on the second host.

It worked for about 10 minutes, now I get a 503 error when trying to visit.  I've given the DNS around 60 hours thus far to propagate.

I would just use the first host for my needs without the second, except the first does not have the resources required to run what I'd like to run on the subdomain.

I've searched through the board and I've followed suggestions, etc.  I can't find another circumstance which this has happened to someone.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else runs into this, after fiddling in WHM on the secondary server, I disabled PHP-FPM and all is well with the world.